How do I remove this recalled door knob?
After hours of fiddling, Googling, reading, etc., I am at a loss. I'm trying to remove the door knob in the images below, and I can't make any progress.
Image #1
Image #2
As you can see in the second image, this is for a Gainsborough door knob with part number 178. Searching for this in particular leads me to believe that I am hitting a dead end because it's possible these are the knobs that were recalled 30 years ago in this recall announcement.
I've seen other posts about Gainsborough knobs in particular recommending unscrewing counter-clockwise, but that's typically for knobs without screws while mine has 2 screws on each side. After removing both sets of 2 screws from each side and the 2 from the latch, both knobs are still stuck. No amount of turning, prying, or pulling does anything. I don't see any place to use a flathead to pop off one of the handles. I'm just at a complete loss.
If I have to end up destroying the knobs to get them off, I can resign myself to that fate if need be. However, I'd much rather not go that route. I would love any insight on how I might go about removing this; there's got to be something simple I am missing. Thank you!

look at the stem between the handle and the backplate. there may be a fixing there.

A picture of the under side will be helpful, where the metal of the handle meets the plate that meets the door.

This is a wild guess, but try spinning the escutcheon about 1/8 turn clockwise.
